# Delete all elements from an array?

Tags: solidity

I am writing a smart contract to be the backend of a game. Instead of using a mapping, I have decided to use an array to store the addresses of accounts who have paid my contract. (I know it is common practice to use a mapping for this but I find them to be confusing)

```
address[] paidPlayers;
```

As players join, their address is added via the following function.

```
function addPlayer(address player) constant returns (address[]) {
   paidPlayers.push(player);
   return paidPlayers;
}
```

Periodically, when a round in the game is completed, I want my contract to reset.  I thus need a way of emptying my paidPlayers array.  How is this done in solidity?  Is there anything like the javascript

```
paidPlayers = [];
```

I have found methods for deleting a specific element but not the array as a whole.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From Solidity Documentation [Tips and Tricks](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/miscellaneous.html#tips-and-tricks)

> Use delete on arrays to delete all its elements.

```
delete paidPlayers;
```

This is exactly the same as `paidPlayers.length = 0`

Comment: Caveat! if the array is too large it will cause a run out of gas error!

An alternative is to use mappings of uint256 and a totalNumberOfElements to handle where to save the values. In case of clear/reset you set totalNumberOfElements = 0.

For inserts, you should use myArray[totalNumberOfElements] = value

Comment: @imazzara You are correct but there's an important difference deleting an array will reset all the data to zero. In a case of mapping you have to explicitely delete each item, if you do not delete it and reuse an index it will still have the previous data.

Comment: Right, but it depends on how you manage the access to them. I mean, you can let users only to get items with something like getItemAtIndex where you check the bounds with the valid totalNumberOfElements instead of making the mapping public.

The rule should be: "If you are not confident about the size of the array, you will need to use mappings to prevent a possible DoS."

Moreover, it saves gas, cause you are re-using the slots instead of empty all of them.

Comment: After deleting an array; how much gas refund will be made? would it be 15.000 or the 15.000 * `length_of_the_array` ? Please see (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/69882/4575) for more detail in question. @Ismael

Comment: This doesn't work for mappings.

Comment: @LukeHutchison The question is about arrays not mappings. It is not possible to delete all elements from a mapping because keys aren't stored.

Comment: @Ismael correct, I know that -- I was just offering some related information. Sorry if you thought it was off-topic.

Comment: Seems ```delete``` has not been supported since 0.6 version. There is no info about it in their press release https://blog.soliditylang.org/2019/12/17/solidity-0.6.0-release-announcement/, but it is mentioned in https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/060-breaking-changes.html?highlight=Pop#explicitness-requirements

Answer (score 6):

You can manually set the array length to 0 with:

```
paidPlayers.length = 0;
```

This will clear all entries in the array.

**Update**: starting with Solidity v0.6, the `length` member is read-only. You can no longer delete an array by setting the `length` to zero.

Comment: Note that from Solidity 0.6 onwards the `length` member is read-only. Using `delete` is now the right approach.

Comment: This answer is no more relevant

Comment: @HaseebSaeed I have updated the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

you can assign the array to a new empty array

```
   paidPlayers=new address[](0);
```

Comment: Is this more or less gas efficient than just deleting the array using Ismael's solution?

Comment: **Update**: it turns out assigning to an empty array is less gas efficient than using `delete`. To see this you can run this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/paulrberg/ec7bb7330a3c54398134ecf95a568cbe) on Remix. The `Foo` contract's method cost 39,951 gas, while the `Bar` contract's method cost 40,030 gas.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the array using assembly assuming it's stored in memory...

```
function _resizeArray(
    address[] memory array,
    uint256 size
) internal pure {
    assembly {
        mstore(array, size)
    }
}
```