# After deleting all elements from an array, how much gas refund will be made?

Tags: solidity

Following [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46214/4575) and [solidity_link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/miscellaneous.html#tips-and-tricks) says that:

> Use delete on arrays to delete all its elements.
>
> ```
> delete dataArray;
> ```
>
> This is exactly the same as `dataArray.length = 0`

---

From this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/543/4575) as I understand that negative gas costs will be 15000.

> The only two OPCODEs with negative gas costs are STORAGEKILL(-15000)
> and GSUICIDEREFUND(-24000).

**[Q]** Overall, after deleting an array; how much gas refund will be made? Would it be only `15000` or `15.000 * 'length_of_the_array'` ?

**=>** For example, I have an array with length of 100. When I delete it how much gas will I be refunded?

**If only `15000`;** then should I traverse all the elements in an array and delete them rather than doing `delete dataArray`?

Something like:

```
for (uint i=0; i< dataArray.length; i++) { 
    delete dataArray[i];
}
```

---

**=>** For example, if I want to delete an mapping that maps a struct (`uint[]` that has 100 items), would it refund `15000` or the gas cost of the `struct` that is pointed (`15000 * 100`).

**If only `15000`;** then should I traverse all the elements mapped by the element as well and delete them rather than doing `delete mappingData` ?

```
mapping(address => uint[]) mappingData;  //'0xabcd' maps to length of the `uint[]` is 100
delete mappingData;
```

Something like:

```
for (uint i=0; i< mappingData[0xabcd].length; i++) {
    delete mappingData[0xabcd][i];
}
```

---

***Some observation:*** If I traverse an delete and delete items one by one, traversing will charge me additional gas cost, maybe equivalent to the refunded gas so where would be the motivation to use `delete`?

Comment: Perhaps what you're missing is that `delete dataArray`/`dataArray.length = 0` will also walk through the array and delete each removed element. So there should be no difference between the two in terms of the total gas refund.

Comment: For a `mapping` you would have to `delete` individual values yourself, as there's no way to enumerate them automatically.

Comment: Also note that the gas refund can only offset up to half of the transaction cost, so it's certainly possible for deleting extra elements to have a net result of costing more. This is especially true if the only thing your transaction is doing is deleting storage.

Comment: As I understand, it is not recommended to do only delete operation in a transaction and its better to do delete operation where in a transaction which has a high gas usage. @smarx

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opcode STORAGEKILL refund only applies to a single slot.

Deleting an array in Solidity is equivalent to deleting all slots used by the array. It should be `15000 * (1 + array_length * item_slots)`.

Here, `item_slots` is the number of storage slots used for each item in the array. For example, for an `uint256` array, each item uses one slot. An array of struct with two `uint256` will use two slots.

For more complex structs, you will have to check the Solidity documentation on how structs are lay out in storage to determine how many slots are used for each item.

For reference, each storage slot uses 32 bytes.

You should be aware the refund is done at the end of the transaction, you have to have enough gas to process each slot upfront. Also, your refund can be at most half of the gas used.

Comment: How is the case on `mapping` still does it delete all the slots? and how `item_size` is calculated and why it is divided by 32? @Ismael

Comment: As I understand, if a function does only `delete dataArray` it won't refund the gas used on the previously transactions that actually set the storage. It will refund the gas used on the transaction that only does `delete dataArray`, and I will charge me additional gas to delete the storage; so what would be the meaning of it ?  @Ismael

Comment: @alper You cannot delete a whole mapping since keys are not stored and you cannot iterate over it. The motivations behind the current refunds gas policy is better as a separate question.

Comment: How about if I delete a `struct`? would it also iterate all variables under it and assign them zero? @Ismael

Comment: It should set to zero all members of the struct.