# what replaces assigning array.length to 0 for clearing it

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/ethereum-developers/the-ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-and-deploy-a-fully-descentralized-dapp-in-ethereum-18f0cf6d7e0e#:%7E:text=%20The%20ultimate%20end-to-end%20tutorial%20to%20create%20and,project%20and%20you%E2%80%99ll%20test%20it%20to...%20More%20) and there's a line where an address array `players` has this done `players.length = 0` which issues this error: `member length is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays`. I get that only pop and push are allowed as well as assigning a new empty array. I was wondering how to perform that last operation in this context.

Comment: How about `delete players`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete all elements from an array](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46209/delete-all-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.11/types.html?highlight=arrays#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour) has an example explaining `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`players.length=0` was allowed before the `solidity 0.6.0`. After the update **length** is now read-only member.

There is a **delete** keyword you can use to delete the **players** array.

```
delete players
```

But the `delete` should never be use to remove a single element from the array.
Since delete leave the gap between the array.

You can see first example over [here](https://github.com/miguelmota/solidity-idiosyncrasies#examples).

```
contract MyContract {
  uint[] array = [1,2,3];

  function removeAtIndex(uint index) returns (uint[]) {
    if (index >= array.length) return;

    for (uint i = index; i < array.length-1; i++) {
      array[i] = array[i+1];
    }

    delete array[array.length-1];
    array.length--;

    return array;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `array.pop()` to delete the last element in an array.